# Haxe in the field

Tags: haxe

I had a fresh look at Haxe again recently and realized that I had overlooked some of its elegance before. But I guess it lacks some visibility among the developers still.

So my question is, does anybody here use it for production? If so, how do you use it? What are the gotchas or difficulties you encounter? Do you recommend it for future projects?

Comment: Yes, I work at a stealth startup in silicon valley using it to build an up-coming social/mobile game.

Answer (score 27):

I use Haxe to develop all my Flash applications, and I love it.  I develop on Linux and with Emacs, 
and I really like how I can make Haxe fit within my preferred development environment.  I just use
simple Makefiles that look something like:

```
project.swf: Project.hx
    haxe project.hxml
```

It's really easy to get started in Haxe, and it's very elegant.  I've
had no problems at all using Haxe as compared to using the Adobe Flash
builders, and have developed a bunch of big projects including [PanningPedagogy](http://pan.sness.net), [The Orchive](http://orchive.cs.uvic.ca),[Cantillion](http://cantillion.sness.net) and [Audioscapes](http://audioscapes.sness.net).

I've released the source code to all of these as GPL on SourceForge, check them out at:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/panning/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/orcaannotator/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/cantillion/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/margridflash/

Answer (score 15):

You might find some useful information in the lists of [Projects Using Haxe](http://old.haxe.org/com/projects) and [People Using Haxe](http://old.haxe.org/com/people).

Answer (score 13):

My company uses Haxe for production use. For programming swf content is absolutly no problem on the technical side. Using it on the server side is a little bit harder. If you Haxe for PHP you sometimes have some problems with typing (this is more or less a PHP problem). The neko vm is very stable and very very fast but it takes some time to get it running with all you other server software (mysql, apache - mod_rewrite), but once you got it you it is very stable.

We used it for generation swf applications, tried the possibilies of Haxe JS. Also we created socket server for a multiplayer game and start to generate all our webpages with Haxe PHP or neko.

The community is very helpful, the documentation is sometimes a little bit to short.

This is only my opinion and the experiences I made.

Answer (score 9):

For those of us who don't know what Haxe is, it's a programming language for developing web apps.  It has multiple compiler targets (Flash, php, JavaScript, and the [Neko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neko_(programming_language)) language's VM)

- [Welcome to haxe](http://haxe.org/) [haxe.org]
- [Haxe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HaXe) entry on Wikipedia

Answer (score 4):

Haxe are currently gaining more popularity as a cross-platform development (mainly for game development) tools thanks to NME/OpenFL: http://www.openfl.org/

Write once in Haxe and deploy it to Flash, Android, iOS, and more..

Answer (score 1):

HaxeJS is very good for web production, it allows to use all the underlying js modules while giving extra abilities like pre-processor, typed fields, conditional-compilation, classes, haxe libraries, refactoring and auto-completion from IDE etc.. plus its very quick to compile and output ready-to-use js files.

I haven't tried microsoft typescript, but so far I've been using HaxeJS for both client and server (nodejs) on a few production projects and it feels a great choice. The only issue is if i want to share js libraries or npm modules with others, I'll probably need to rewrite the js by hand then.

Answer (score 0):

We used it at a previous internship, for an internal web system. We only compiled to js and I just once compiled some minor code to both js and C#. I can say it worked quite well and many custom widgets were made at the time. Debugging the produced js wasn't that bad either, but it sometimes didn't produce the code you wanted it to (I remember one string comparison issue in js, where the reference was being compared instead of the value). The code was deployed in production and had worked fine for years. I'm pretty sure they still use it today.

That was in 2013, I haven't used it since. One problem I did have was trying to compile code made in version 2.08 using version 2.10. It needed some minor, but non-obvious adjustments. I can't quite comment on more recent releases, but I'd be a bit careful on not breaking large pieces of code by upgrading to new versions of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You compile, haxelib run flow run "target" in target you type for example web, and thats all, in your bin, folder you get your files, remember to configure your project.flow file acording to your target and project.