# Best practices for multiplatform form based gui apps with haxe

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, haxe

I am currently exploring how to write platformindependant software that have forms with inputfieleds (fat client in java or dotnet as well 
as web apps in asp.net or java jsf).

I stumbled over
[last updated 2009: is-haxe-worth-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384647/is-haxe-worth-learning)

I read among others some [haxe tutorial](http://haxelearning.wikispaces.com) and the the [wikopedia article about haxe](http://haxelearning.wikispaces.com)
 and it looks quite promising.

- Are there any best practises how to seperate haxe-businesslogic from platformdependent-gui-logic?
- or is there even a haxe-gui-abstraction layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one library that is currently developed for cross-platform NME use. You can check it out [on GitHub](https://github.com/MatthijsKamstra/haXe-NME-UI).

It's still in development phase and has a few to-dos : It can use some help.

If you're interested in doing one-source-cross-platform things, you can also look at the [conditional compilation](http://haxe.org/ref/conditionals) and at the ["**cross**" tagged haxelibs](http://lib.haxe.org/t/cross).

There is also a few MVC framework in Haxe, like [MMVC](http://lib.haxe.org/p/mmvc), which is a port of [AS3 Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/).

Good luck, and share what you're doing to the community =)