# How can Haxe convert flash content into objective c?

Tags: iphone, flash, haxe

I went through many links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384647/is-haxe-worth-learning),[this](http://haxe.org) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321204/haxe-in-the-field), but not getting good direction to move with. I need to implement some flash content in my iPhone app. Can anybody help me with some good tutorials to move on with the conversion process. Thanks in advance.

Suppose I am having a flash air iOS app and I need to convert the whole app in objective c for say adding some features like APNS then I have to do some needful. I want to convert the air iOS based app in objective c for same thing and hence need a tool like Haxe. Kindly help me with some tutorial or any other tool available. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to check out http://www.haxenme.org/ to support iOS

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Haxe is a new language (by new, I mean different than others, not recently developed). It's compiler can compile Haxe code to target different platforms like C++ / C#, Flash, NekoVM, PHP and JavaScript. That said, its syntax is similar to Flash ActionScript.

To conclude, Haxe does not convert one language to another. It is a language in itself, which can be compiled targetting different platforms. So if you can port your {insert language name here} code to Haxe, then you can compile it to any of the languages mentioned in http://haxe.org/doc/intro

Comment: Thanks Pranav. But I already went through that link. What I need is provide me link of some good tutorials if you have some.thanks.

Comment: ya but i could not find any iPhone specific.

Comment: If you want to compile ActionScript and run it on iPhone, check out http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html

Comment: Suppose I am having a flash air iOS app and I need to convert the whole app in objective c for say adding some features like APNS then I have to do some needful. I want to convert the air iOS based app in objective c for same thing.

Comment: oh.. Then you need to rewrite the code in iOS. I don't think there is any tool available to convert AS3 to Obj-C

Comment: What if the app is already launched in store. I hope you can get idea that you can not get exact look with objective c like flash app. For the same reason I was finding some tool.

Comment: Well in that case you will have to (a) Find a workaround in AIR or (b) not mind if the look is different.

Comment: If APNS = "Apple Push Notification Service", you don't need to convert it to ObjC, you could use an ANE extension for Adobe AIR, someone even already wrote one for that: http://flashsimulations.com/2011/12/16/apple-push-notification-service-native-extension-for-adobe-air/